# How download more than one zip file using asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have five zip file in temp folder for download that file. My aim is download all file but now it download first file.

I try this code for download all file

Dim i As Integer

```
Dim TxtLocalSysName As String = Request.UserHostName
Dim readStream As FileStream
Dim writeStream As FileStream
Try
    For i = 0 To lstdownload.Items.Count - 1
        Dim filePath As String = Me.Label5.Text + "\" + lstdownload.Items(i).Text
        Dim targetFile As System.IO.FileInfo = New System.IO.FileInfo(filePath)
        readStream = New FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open)
        Dim length As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(readStream.Length)
        'This is the buffer.
        Dim byteFile() As Byte = New Byte(length) {}
        readStream.Read(byteFile, 0, length)
        readStream.Close()
        Dim localPath As String = "\\" & TxtLocalSysName & "\c$\downloads"
        If Not Directory.Exists(localPath) Then
            Directory.CreateDirectory(localPath)
        End If
        writeStream = New FileStream(localPath & "\" & targetFile.Name, FileMode.Create)
        writeStream.Write(byteFile, 0, length)
        writeStream.Close()
    Next i
Catch ex As Exception
    Console.WriteLine("The process failed: {0}", ex.ToString())
Finally
    readStream.Close()
    readStream.Dispose()
    writeStream.Close()
    writeStream.Dispose()

End Try
```

I put the website in server side so all zip file download in server side temp folder. I need all zip file in client side temp folder

Comment: Zip the zips...

Comment: Any one can reply for my doubt